# how to get boost::posix_time::ptime from formatted string

Tags: c++, boost

I have a formated string like "2012-03-28T08:00:00".
i want to get year, month(in string format),date,hour, min ,sec and day (in string format).
can any one suggest me the easiest way to do it in boost.

thanks

Comment: Is your string always in the ISO format you've asked about in your question or do you need it to accept any format of string?

Answer (score 11):

If the existing from_string() methods do not suit your needs then you can use a time input facet that allows you to customise the format from which the string is parsed.

In your case you can use the ISO extended format string so you can use the following code to parse your strings:

```
    boost::posix_time::time_input_facet *tif = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet;
    tif->set_iso_extended_format();
    std::istringstream iss("2012-03-28T08:00:00");
    iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), tif));
    iss >> abs_time;
    std::cout << abs_time << std::endl;
```

Comment: Nice but that "new" is ugly. One can get around it constructing the facet like so: "boost::posix_time::time_input_facet tif(1)". The argument "1" means no funny business with ownership and lifetimes ...

Answer (score 9):

Without using facets;

`ptime dateTime = boost::date_time::parse_delimited_time<ptime>(string, 'T');`

The two `from*_string` functions have limits on what formats are converted.

- Does not accept 'T': `time_from_string(s)`.
- Does not accept '-': `from_iso_string(s)`.

Roundtripping ISO 8601 date/time in boost;

`std::string date = to_iso_extended_string(dateTime);`