# Should i free memory when i am using boost::posix_time::time_facet

Tags: c++, datetime, memory, boost

I have a method that returns the expiration date of a subscription and uses `boost::posix_time::time_facet` to convert Unix time format to string. In tutorials I've seen, `time_facet` is created using the "new" keyword, but I haven't seen any examples using "delete" ([like in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484232/how-to-get-boostposix-timeptime-from-formatted-string)). Should I free memory after using `time_facet` or does the `stringstream` automatically handle memory deallocation?
Here is my piece of code, does it has memory leak?

```
nlohmann::json GetExpireDate::ExecutePayload(ClientHandle& clientHandle)
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime pt = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(m_SubFromPacket.GetEndDate());
    std::stringstream ss;
    auto timeFacet = std::make_unique<boost::posix_time::time_facet>("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), timeFacet.get()));
    ss << pt;
    return {{ "expire_date", ss.str()}};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't contain a leak, but it does contain a double free. The locale takes ownership of its second argument. You must not delete it yourself (or let a `unique_ptr` do it).